# Hibernate custom sequence generator - Table doesn't exist

Tags: spring-boot, java-8, hibernate-5.x

I'm using a custom class to generate id:

```
public class StringPrefixedSequenceIdGenerator extends SequenceStyleGenerator
```

Also using this class on entity attribute:

```
@Id
    @GenericGenerator(name = "pipeline_seq_generator", strategy = "com.model.StringPrefixedSequenceIdGenerator", parameters = {
            @Parameter(name = StringPrefixedSequenceIdGenerator.INCREMENT_PARAM, value = "50") })
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "pipeline_seq_generator", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "pipeline_id", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 100)
    public String getPipelineId() {
        return this.pipelineId;
    }
```

The problem is that hibernate still try to get the sequence from database:
select next_val as id_val from pipeline_seq_generator for update

**Error: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'table.pipeline_seq_generator' doesn't exist**

EDIT: The @Override generate method is causing hibernate to call sequence from database when I pass super.generate(session,object) as a parameter in my method :

```
@Override
    public Serializable generate(SharedSessionContractImplementor session,
            Object object) throws HibernateException {
        return String.format(format, LocalDate.now(), super.generate(session, object));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the implementation of generate method to not use the super.generate(session, object):

```
@Override
    public Serializable generate(SharedSessionContractImplementor session,
            Object object) throws HibernateException {
        LocalTime localTime = LocalTime.now();
        return prefix + String.format(format, LocalDate.now()) + localTime.getHour() + localTime.getMinute() + localTime.getSecond();
    }
```

In this model I'm only using my implementation without use sequence database.

Answer (score 0):

In
public void configure(Type type, Properties properties,
ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry) throws MappingException {

// ignore the (String) Type input parameter and use a new LongType()
super.configure(new LongType(), properties, serviceRegistry);

String Types can not be generated by a sequence in hibernate (liquibase)

after this you can just use:
String toString = super.generate(session, object).toString();
in the generate method and add a prefix .